# Randomly generating a WoW Classic character

Tags: c#

Full code can be found on my [GitHub](https://github.com/Webbarrr/WoWSelector) but more details are included here.

I decided I'd like to level up some new characters on WoW Classic & I thought it would be fun if I randomly generated some combinations.

The idea is that you would generate a random faction (`Horde` or `Alliance`), then one of the races & finally one of the available classes.

I can't put my finger on why, but I'm not overly happy with the outcome. It's a combination of things really. The code works of course, but I can't help but feel it could be better.

So - the gist of it is this.

We have factions -

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using WoWSelector.Library.Races;

namespace WoWSelector.Library.Factions
{

    public class Alliance : IFaction
    {
        public List<IRace> GetRaces()
        {
            var races = new List<IRace>
            {
                new Human(),
                new Dwarf(),
                new NightElf(),
                new Gnome()
            };


            return races;
        }
    }
}
```

And we have races -

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WoWSelector.Library.Races
{
    public class Human : AllianceBase, IRace
    {
        public List<string> GetClasses()
        {
            return this.GetPlayableClasses();
        }
    }
}
```

I think this is where it gets quite messy. All races inherit from a corresponding base class -

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using WoWSelector.Library.Classes;

namespace WoWSelector.Library.Races
{
    public class AllianceBase : ClassBase
    {
        public List<string> GetPlayableClasses()
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<IRace, string>();

            var classes = new List<string>
            {
                Warrior,
                Paladin,
                Rogue,
                Priest,
                Mage,
                Warlock
            };
            foreach (var item in classes)
            {
                dict.Add(new Human(), item);
            }

            classes = new List<string>
            {
                Warrior,
                Paladin,
                Hunter,
                Rogue,
                Priest
            };
            foreach (var item in classes)
            {
                dict.Add(new Dwarf(), item);
            }

            classes = new List<string>
            {
                Warrior,
                Hunter,
                Rogue,
                Priest,
                Druid
            };
            foreach (var item in classes)
            {
                dict.Add(new NightElf(), item);
            }

            classes = new List<string>
            {
                Warrior,
                Rogue,
                Mage,
                Warlock
            };
            foreach (var item in classes)
            {
                dict.Add(new Gnome(), item);
            }

            return this.GetPlayableCLasses(dict, this.GetType().Name);
        }
    }
}
```

And the faction specific base classes inherit from -

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using WoWSelector.Library.Races;

namespace WoWSelector.Library.Classes
{
    public class ClassBase
    {
        public const string Warrior = "Warrior";
        public const string Paladin = "Paladin";
        public const string Rogue = "Rogue";
        public const string Priest = "Priest";
        public const string Mage = "Mage";
        public const string Warlock = "Warlock";
        public const string Hunter = "Hunter";
        public const string Druid = "Druid";
        public const string Shaman = "Shaman";


        protected List<string> GetPlayableCLasses(Dictionary<IRace, string> keyValuePairs, string raceName)
        {
            var playableClasses = keyValuePairs.Where(d => d.Key.GetType().Name == raceName);
            var listOfPlayableClasses = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in playableClasses)
            {
                listOfPlayableClasses.Add(item.Value);
            }

            return listOfPlayableClasses;
        }
    }
}
```

I dislike how much I've repeated steps in the example `AllianceBase` class. I'm sure there's a smarter way of doing it but I couldn't figure it out.

And of course, how it all comes together in the form of a controller class to be called in my main method -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using WoWSelector.Library.Factions;
using WoWSelector.Library.Races;

namespace WoWSelector.Library
{
    public class SelectorController
    {
        private readonly Random random;

        public SelectorController()
        {
            random = new Random();
        }

        public IFaction GetFaction()
        {
            var factions = new List<IFaction>
            {
                new Alliance(),
                new Horde()
            };

            return factions[random.Next(0, factions.Count)];
        }

        public IRace GetRace(IFaction faction)
        {
            if (faction is null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(faction));

            var races = faction.GetRaces();
            return races[random.Next(0, races.Count)];
        }

        public string GetClass(IRace race)
        {
            if (race is null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(race));

            var classes = race.GetClasses();
            return classes[random.Next(0, classes.Count)];
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate this is on the chunky side but would appreciate any feedback people are willing to give to help me improve.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why you've gone this far using the classes instead of `Enum`. I can understand if you're planning to include some functionalities to each class, but if is it just for the current context, then it would be useless.

For instance, Warrior, Hunter, Rogue ..etc. are some work descriptions to Races like Human, Orc, Troll...etc. And Alliance, Horde... are another type of these races. So Race is the main type, while others are just some descriptive types of these races.

Since they're all descriptive types, we can use `Enum` :

```
public enum RaceType
{
    Warrior,
    Paladin,
    Rogue,
    Priest,
    Mage,
    Warlock,
    Hunter,
    Druid,
    Shaman
}

public enum RaceName
{
    Orc,
    Troll,
    Tauren,
    Undead,
    Human,
    Dwarf,
    NightElf,
    Gnome
}

public enum RaceFaction
{
    Horde,
    Alliance
}
```

Now, we can make a model class which will hold all that information

```
public class Race
{
    public RaceType Type { get; set; }

    public RaceName Name { get; set; }

    public RaceFaction Faction { get; set; }

    public Race() { }

    public Race(RaceType type, RaceName name, RaceFaction faction) 
    {
        Type = type;
        Name = name;
        Faction = faction;
    }
}
```

Now, we use it on the main class :

```
public class WoWSelector
{
    private readonly List<Race> Races = new List<Race>();
    
    private Random _random = new Random();

    private int _randomIndex => _random.Next(0, Races.Count);

    private IEnumerable<Race> GetAlliance()
    {
         // I have never played WOW, but I assumed it's a fixed data since you've defined it on your Alliance class.
        return new List<Race>
        {
            new Race(RaceType.Warrior, RaceName.Human, RaceFaction.Alliance),
            new Race(RaceType.Paladin, RaceName.Human, RaceFaction.Alliance),
            new Race(RaceType.Rogue, RaceName.Human, RaceFaction.Alliance),
            new Race(RaceType.Priest, RaceName.Human, RaceFaction.Alliance),
            new Race(RaceType.Mage, RaceName.Human, RaceFaction.Alliance),
            new Race(RaceType.Warlock, RaceName.Human, RaceFaction.Alliance),
            new Race(RaceType.Warrior, RaceName.Dwarf, RaceFaction.Alliance),
            new Race(RaceType.Paladin, RaceName.Dwarf, RaceFaction.Alliance),
            new Race(RaceType.Hunter, RaceName.Dwarf, RaceFaction.Alliance),
            new Race(RaceType.Rogue, RaceName.Dwarf, RaceFaction.Alliance),
            new Race(RaceType.Priest, RaceName.Dwarf, RaceFaction.Alliance),
            new Race(RaceType.Warrior, RaceName.NightElf, RaceFaction.Alliance),
            new Race(RaceType.Hunter, RaceName.NightElf, RaceFaction.Alliance),
            new Race(RaceType.Rogue, RaceName.NightElf, RaceFaction.Alliance),
            new Race(RaceType.Priest, RaceName.NightElf, RaceFaction.Alliance),
            new Race(RaceType.Druid, RaceName.NightElf, RaceFaction.Alliance),
            new Race(RaceType.Druid, RaceName.NightElf, RaceFaction.Alliance),
            new Race(RaceType.Warrior, RaceName.Gnome, RaceFaction.Alliance),
            new Race(RaceType.Rogue, RaceName.Gnome, RaceFaction.Alliance),
            new Race(RaceType.Mage, RaceName.Gnome, RaceFaction.Alliance),
            new Race(RaceType.Warlock, RaceName.Gnome, RaceFaction.Alliance)
        };

    }

    private IEnumerable<Race> GetHorde()
    {
        return new List<Race>
        {
            new Race(RaceType.Warrior, RaceName.Orc, RaceFaction.Horde),
            new Race(RaceType.Hunter, RaceName.Orc, RaceFaction.Horde),
            new Race(RaceType.Rogue, RaceName.Orc, RaceFaction.Horde),
            new Race(RaceType.Shaman, RaceName.Orc, RaceFaction.Horde),
            new Race(RaceType.Warlock, RaceName.Orc, RaceFaction.Horde),
            new Race(RaceType.Warrior, RaceName.Undead, RaceFaction.Horde),
            new Race(RaceType.Priest, RaceName.Undead, RaceFaction.Horde),
            new Race(RaceType.Rogue, RaceName.Undead, RaceFaction.Horde),
            new Race(RaceType.Mage, RaceName.Undead, RaceFaction.Horde),
            new Race(RaceType.Warlock, RaceName.Undead, RaceFaction.Horde),
            new Race(RaceType.Warrior, RaceName.Tauren, RaceFaction.Horde),
            new Race(RaceType.Hunter, RaceName.Tauren, RaceFaction.Horde),
            new Race(RaceType.Shaman, RaceName.Tauren, RaceFaction.Horde),
            new Race(RaceType.Druid, RaceName.Tauren, RaceFaction.Horde),
            new Race(RaceType.Warrior, RaceName.Troll, RaceFaction.Horde),
            new Race(RaceType.Hunter, RaceName.Troll, RaceFaction.Horde),
            new Race(RaceType.Rogue, RaceName.Troll, RaceFaction.Horde),
            new Race(RaceType.Priest, RaceName.Troll, RaceFaction.Horde),
            new Race(RaceType.Mage, RaceName.Troll, RaceFaction.Horde),
            new Race(RaceType.Shaman, RaceName.Troll, RaceFaction.Horde)
        };
    }

    public WoWSelector()
    {
        Races.AddRange(GetAlliance());
        Races.AddRange(GetHorde());
    }

    public Race GetRandomRace()
    {
        return Races[_randomIndex];
    }
}
```

For `GetAlliance` and `GetHorde` basically, I extracted your classes into methods. If you're expecting to initiate a `new` random `Race`, then you can get rid of them, and just use random to generate new `Race` instead.

Then you can do this :

```
var wow = new WoWSelector();

for(int x=0; x < 5; x++)
{
    var race = wow.GetRandomRace();

    Console.WriteLine($"{race.Type} : {race.Name}  : {race.Faction}");
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you, busy weekend, but did appreciate your feedback.

As I mentioned on the other answer I was given, I did try to use Enums to start with but I think that I'm very guilty of over-engineering things from the beginning of a project & my biggest takeaway should be to think more around more elegant solutions.

I've taken away your comments on Enum & applied it to another project I'm working on at the moment & it's making life easier to not just create classes for the sake of it. Thank you

Comment: I would move methods like `GetAlliance()` to their own class (e.g. `AllianceRetriever`) perhaps even have them as static properties instead of methods, and use loops to construct the various `Race` objects.

Answer (score 4):

I think the main problem you have here is that you have very tight coupling, and you've made a **bunch** of classes that don't really do anything. Just because you can make a class/object doesn't mean you should. In this case, your use-case is straightforward enough that the simplest solution is likely the best.

For example - the fact that you have 8 classes to represent the race, that are all *literally* identical besides for the class name is a huge code smell. Despite this, you then seem to fallback to strings all the time, for no apparent reason.

I also noticed that you instantiate your classes all over the place, despite there not being any instance-specific behavior it actually drives.

For your limited use case, just making some switch statements is going to be your best bet:

```
enum RaceEnum {
    Gnome,
    Dwarf,
    Human,
    NightElf,
    Orc,
    Tauren,
    Troll,
    Undead
}

enum ClassEnum {
    Warrior,
    Paladin,
    Rogue,
    Priest,
    Mage,
    Warlock,
    Hunter,
    Druid,
    Shaman
}

enum FactionEnum {
    Alliance,
    Horde
}

class WowClassicCharacter {
    public RaceEnum Race { get; set; }

    public ClassEnum Class { get; set; }

    public FactionEnum Faction { get; set; }

    public WowClassicRace(RaceEnum race, ClassEnum klass, FactionEnum faction) {
        if (!WowClassicCharacter.raceIsValidForFaction(race, faction)) {
            throw new Exception("The given race and faction are not compatible");
        }
        if (!WowClassicCharacter.classIsValidForRace(klass, race) {
            throw new Exception("The given class and race are not compatible");
        }
        Race = race;
        Class = klass;
        Faction = faction;
    }

    public static boolean raceIsValidForFaction(RaceEnum race, FactionEnum faction) {
        return faction switch
        {
            FactionEnum.Alliance => race switch 
            {
                RaceEnum.Human => true,
                RaceEnum.Dwarf => true,
                RaceEnum.NightElf => true,
                RaceEnum.Gnome => true,
                _ => false
            },
            FactionEnum.Horde => race switch
            {
                RaceEnum.Orc => true,
                RaceEnum.Troll => true,
                RaceEnum.Tauren => true,
                RaceEnum.Undead => true,
                _ => false
            }
        };
    }

    public static boolean classIsValidForRace(ClassEnum klass, RaceEnum race) {
        return race switch
        {
            RaceEnum.Human => klass switch
            {
                ClassEnum.Warrior => true,
                ClassEnum.Paladin => true,
                ClassEnum.Rogue => true,
                ClassEnum.Priest => true,
                ClassEnum.Mage => true,
                ClassEnum.Warlock => true,
                _ => false
            },
            RaceEnum.Dwarf => klass switch
            {
                ClassEnum.Warrior => true,
                ClassEnum.Paladin => true,
                ClassEnum.Hunter => true,
                ClassEnum.Rogue => true,
                ClassEnum.Priest => true,
                _ => false
            },
            // etc
            _ => false
        };
    }
}
```

It would be relatively straightforward to make a config file, or a database, or whatever back this up instead of hardcoded switch statements, but it seems like your use case doesn't require the complexity, so keep it simple.

Then your controller looks like this:

```
public class SelectorController
{
    private readonly Random random;

    public SelectorController()
    {
        random = new Random();
    }

    private T GetRandomEnumValue<T>() where T: system.Enum
    {
        return random.Next(0, Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)).Length);
    }

    public FactionEnum GetFaction()
    {
        return GetRandomEnumValue<FactionEnum>();
    }

    public RaceEnum GetRace(FactionEnum faction)
    {
        RaceEnum race;
        do      
        {
            race = GetRandomEnumValue<RaceEnum>();
        }
        while (!WowClassicCharacter.raceIsValidForFaction(race, faction));
        return race;
    }

    public ClassEnum GetClass(RaceEnum race)
    {
        ClassEnum klass;
        do      
        {
            klass = GetRandomEnumValue<ClassEnum>();
        }
        while (!WowClassicCharacter.classIsValidForRace(klass, race));
        return klass;
    }
}
```

You could pretty easily make some smarter methods than just randomly generating until it is valid, but this gets the point across.

Final takeaways:

1. Don't make and use classes just because you can
2. Enums are better than strings
3. When in doubt, prefer simple solutions

Apologies for any errors - my C# is rusty and I wrote this all in the answer box.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you - your feedback was appreciated.

I appreciate the final takeaways. I think 1 & 3 are definitely an issue that I create for myself by trying to over-engineer things from the start of a project. I did toy with using Enums to begin with but couldn't figure out a way of getting it to work with the way I was trying to lay things out. Thank you again for your help